# Forging a signature on NC car title

Tags: forgery, car

My now ex boyfriend and I had 4 cars. They are all in my name, my insurance. One needed some "repairs" I was told so he took it to a mechanic. A week later I drive by the mechanic shop to see "my" car with updated accessories (camper thing on top). I asked my ex boyfriend and he said he sold it to the owner of the shop. Surprised, by the deception, I still asked "Don't I need to go buy and sign the title?" to which he answered no he took care of it. Isn't is a crime to forge my name on a title that is supposed to be signed by a notary? He also up and left and took the other cars and the titles in my name to Florida. I can't cancel insurance on them because they are all still in my name. What can I do?

Comment: "supposed to be signed by a notary". Why do you think the sale of a car needs to be signed by a notary? That's typically only the case for selling houses.

Comment: I meant it has to be signed in front of a notary and notarized

Comment: If that's really the case (which I doubt), then even the buyer would have committed a crime by not expecting so.

Comment: @PMF Incorrect, you are unfamiliar with US law. In the US, to sell a car (boat, motorcycle, trailer and in some states, ATVs and similar) you have to transfer the title. To effect a transfer of the title, the seller must make a notarized signature on the official title document, then submit the document to the state's department of motor vehicles, which then issues a new title document under the new owner's name. This is a matter of US state law.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't the obvious answer to call the police about someone stealing four of your cars?

Comment: @user71659 Ok, understood. But that would mean that either the signature of the notary was forged, too, or the buyer didn't correctly check the document.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't is a crime to forge my name on a title that is supposed to be signed by a notary?

Yes, this is absolutely a crime. I'm not a lawyer, but at a minimum this is theft (and possibly fraud). You own the cars, not him; he definitely does not have the legal right to sell something that legally belongs to someone else. In fact, given the value of what was stolen, this would likely be grand larceny (or the equivalent) in many jurisdictions.

> He also up and left and took the other cars and the titles in my name to Florida.

This is unquestionably theft.

As far as options, I'd encourage you to file a police report right away; they should be able to help you recover your stolen property. You could also talk to a lawyer about your options for a civil lawsuit.

Answer (score -2):

#### It is a crime to forge your signature on a title.

It's also a crime to take cars titled in your name away from you to another state.

The shop does not now own your car, it was fraudulently sold to them.  If you want your car back you will need to go to the police and tell them your car was criminally sold.  Don't cancel insurance, because it's still your car.  After you call the police, call your insurance.
You don't need a lawyer to do any of this, that will just cost you money.  The shop can go after your ex for their money.

Comment: `Don't cancel insurance because it's still your car.` It would still be wise to make the insurance company aware (in writing) of the theft. If the ex-boyfriend trashes the car, the insurance might refuse to cover expenses, or increase her premium, or do all sort of negative actions that will be hard to undo.